# Symfony 4 session expire too soon

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, session-cookies, symfony4

My php session with Symfony 4.0 expire too soon even if I set it up for several days in `config/packages/framework.yaml`.

```
framework:

{...}
session:
    handler_id: ~
    cookie_lifetime: 604800
{...}
```

When the user complete the signin process, he can navigate on the website and, if he return after few minutes, he doesn't need to signin again.

But if he return after 1 or 2 hours (don't know precisely) the session is expired and he must sign in again.

One of the solution that seems worked, was to change what you see above in:

```
handler_id: session.handler.native_file
save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
cookie_lifetime: 604800
```

Unfortunately that solution solved the problem in the dev environment, but crashed the app once that I pulled the code on the server.

Comment: maybe you have no rigths to change php.ini on you server: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-lifetime

Comment: How can I understand if my Symfony Config file is overriding my php ini file? @myxaxa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Problem solved**.

The problem was *save_path*. Just use the parameters suggested in the [official Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/session/sessions_directory.html). In this way your cookies will be correctly stored.

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    cookie_lifetime: 604800
```